# "Use F1, F2 as standard function keys" no longer there: how can I control my volume through keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, sound-volume

Apparently this option is now gone in the keyboard settings on OSX Lion, or maybe it does not appear because I am using a Dell keyboard

[image]

Now, I am not particularly concerned about it. If I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, I get the dashboard. The problem is that I have no keys to set the volume anymore. How can I set the volume, considering I can't create a keyboard shortcut (there's no menu name to bind) ?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the only answer (other than buy a mac keyboard): https://superuser.com/questions/61001/how-do-i-press-the-fn-key-using-a-pc-keyboard-on-a-mac